# DATEDIFF rounding to the nearest 30 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using `datediff` to get the difference between two datetimes:

```
DATEDIFF(hh, CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
    + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered] AS TIME), 
   CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
    + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS [Hours TurnAround]
```

I don't understand the behavior that I am getting from this statement but what I need is anything that is  `>= :30, round up, if not, round down,`

**question** how do I get it to round down when less than 30 minutes and round the hours up if greater or equal to 30 minutes?

Comment: aaron sory about that, thank you for helping with ormatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should calculate the `DATEDIFF` in minutes and do a `ROUND` then:

```
ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(MINUTES, CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Entered] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Entered] AS TIME), CAST(CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Date Completed] AS DATE) AS DATETIME) 
                      + CAST(dbo.QuickLabDump.[Time Completed] AS TIME)) AS FLOAT)/60,0)  AS [Hours TurnAround]
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. I created a Scalar-Valued-Function with that nice statement.